# Edge constantly hides my extensions from the toolbar

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

Why does Edge constantly hide my extensions from the toolbar?

I need to disable/enable (or, alternatively, unhide) one of them and then all of them are visible again. But then (maybe tomorrow, maybe after few hours, I have not tested), Edge hides them again.

Is it a bug or some unidentified setting? I remember this behavior started to happen about a month or two ago.

**Here is what I mean**

Fine. The extension icons are visible on toolbar:

[image]

Not fine. Edge have removed the extension icons from the toolbar for some reason (it do it almost each day!):

[image]

To make them visible again, I need to press the extension button and then enable the "eye" in front of any of the extensions. Then *all* of the extensions will be shown on the toolbar again:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "hide my extensions from the toolbar"?

Comment: @harrymc I have added images.

Comment: It seems the browser is not saving the settings. Try running it as Admin, and then restoring the extensions via Eye button.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happening in our tenant. We have the GPO set to enable specific approved extensions and block the install of all others. After upgrade to latest Edge (103.0.1264.37), they are constantly being hidden and signed out of, which is the REALLY annoying part. I've opened a case with MS Support.

Today I did some testing by moving back to the prior build and this issue DOES NOT occur with it. So something is obviously up with 103.0.1264.37.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer that can be marked as "solved". Perhaps use it for a comment instead?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer that can be marked as "solved". Perhaps use it for a comment instead?

Answer (score 0):

try following this guide, configuring the extension policy under:

HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\

using:

"toolbar_state": "default_shown"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-manage-extensions-ref-guide

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1147803)